# developer tools for os' other than windows

Tags: linux, macos, ide, solaris

I currently use visual studio 2008 for creating projects that can run on windows. Can you recommend me of other tools that can be used to develop applications for other operating systems?(Linux, Mac, Solaris)
The most prominent programming languages will do(C++, C#, F#)
And scripting languages(PHP, Perl, etc)

Comment: What languages will you be using? What OS versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A somewhat similar commercial IDE on Linux is [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/).

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) are free alternatives for development on many platforms.

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and [vim](http://www.vim.org/) give you lots of functionality, with a bit coarser interface.

Answer (score 5):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) strong Java focus, but support for a wide variety of other languages and is cross platform.

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) for cross platform c# fun

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X, Apple provides XCode which is a pretty decent IDE and you can't beat the price.

It handles Java, C, Objective-C and C++ apps out of the box, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

[Padre, the Perl IDE](http://padre.perlide.org/) can be used to develop applications in Perl. It is cross platform and since Perl is (mostly) cross platform, you can develop applications for other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, I sometimes just use [nano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano_%28text_editor%29) (with [syntax highlighting](http://wiki.linuxhelp.net/index.php/Nano_Syntax_Highlighting)), makefiles and subversion. It has the advantage of being really fast over ssh, and unless you need syntax highlighting, Netbeans and Eclipse are overkill.

The languages that can be highlighted in nano by just uncommenting a line in the nanorc file are: asm, awk, c, c++, css, html, java, objective-c, ocaml, patch, perl, php, pov, python, ruby and sh. (It also has highlighting for non-programming things like email and man pages)

Answer (score 0):

For C programming which is very frequent on Unix especially for older programs, the best combination is make + gcc with a good editor.  Emacs has good integration with C source, and compiler output.